# monerod.service: Can't open PID file

Tags: monerod, monero-wallet-cli, systemd

I'm using the following guide in order to setup a Monero node on my computer:

[Monero Node Guide](https://freedomnode.com/blog/how-to-install-and-set-up-full-monero-node-on-linux/)

I am on step 4 and when I run `sudo journalctl -fu monerod.service` I get the following log:

```
monerod.service: Can't open PID file /home/andy/.bitmonero/monerod.pid (yet?) after start: Operation not permitted
```

Here is the source code for my `monerod.service` file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Monero Full Node
After=network.target

[Service]
User=monero
Group=monero

Type=forking
PIDFile=/home/andy/.bitmonero/monerod.pid

ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/monerod --restricted-rpc --block-sync-size 50 --confirm-external-bind --config-file /home/andy>

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When I run `monerod --config-file /home/andy/.bitmonero/monerod.conf status` I get the following error:

```
Error: Couldn't connect to daemon: 127.0.0.1:18081
```

I'm not sure how to fix either of these issues, does anybody know how I am supposed to move forward from here?  I am so lost!

Comment: 1) `--config-file /home/andy>` is missing the rest of the path 2) there is no `--detach` 3) please post the content of your monerod config file in the question 4) have you created the monero user and group specified in your service? 5) does the monero user have write access to the `/home/andy/.bitmonero` directory?

Comment: The blog post you follow  is outdated and buggy. I'd recommend to get binaries from https://www.getmonero.org/it/downloads/ and follow their instructions.